# Eclipse ignores font color changes after restart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit, eclipse-mars

I'm using Eclipse EE Mars 2 with dark theme. All uncommitted files in my project appear with black font whats barely visible on a gray background. I know that I can change font color by going to:
 `Preferences > Appearance > Color and Fonts > Git > Uncommited Change (Foreground)` 
[image]

Works fine after I change color and apply changes but it's just a temporary solution because when I restart Eclipse all changes are gone. It's very inconvenient to change font color each time I run Eclipse, does anyone know how to change egit font color permanently?

Comment: Have you tried setting *Preferences -> Oomph -> Setup Tasks -> Skip automatic task execution at startup time*? You can also selectively modify properties in the *Preferences Recorder*.

Comment: Thanks, after I've unchecked /instance/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.egit.ut.UncommittedChangeForegroundColor in Preferences Recorder color stays the same after restart.

Comment: For better visibility, I've written a small answer to wrap things up, please feel free to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Oomph](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph) plugin is resetting your preferences at startup. The following approaches are possible:

- Completely disable this behaviour by enabling the following parameter
  in Eclipse's preferences: *Preferences -> Oomph -> Setup Tasks ->
  Skip automatic task execution at startup time*.
- Selectively disable
  recording for that specific preference (as mentioned in your comment,
  `/instance/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.egit.ut.Uncom‌​mittedChangeForegrou‌​ndColor`
  in your case). To access the recorder, go to *Preferences -> Oomph ->
  Setup Tasks -> Preference Recorder*.
- Modify the value of the recorded
  preference by selecting it from the *Preference Recorder* screen and
  clicking on the *Open recorder target file* icon.